# Auto answer yes for command `gcloud compute instance-templates delete`

Tags: automation, gcloud

To delete a gcloud instance template, we call

```
gcloud compute instance-templates delete TEMPLATE_NAME
```

But we have to answer a Y/n question which is not favored for automation bash script. We want auto answer yes, how?

p.s.

My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=gcloud%20compute%20instance-templates%20delete%20auto%20answer%20yes&oq=gcloud%20compute%20instance-templates%20delete%20auto%20answer%20yes&aqs=chrome..69i57.11271j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for this question results little helpful.

Manual page of the command also has nothing about any other parameter.

```
gcloud help   compute instance-templates delete
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`gcloud` has a set of global flags including `--quiet` to disable such prompts:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/

Comment: You lighted up my knowledge on gcloud. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `--quiet` will work for the use case. But syntactically speaking, what it is doing is it is "shutting up" all prompts and all console outputs - which is something you may not want. For more generic solution, the `printf "yes" | ` approach showed by @AmitYadav below maybe preferred. It will show all console outputs as normal, and submit the value `yes` when prompted

Answer (score 9):

I agree that using `--quiet` is the best way in the case of `gcloud` commands.

But for a CLI tool that doesn't have such an option we can explicitly use `printf` like below:

```sh
printf 'yes' | gcloud compute instance-templates delete TEMPLATE_NAME
```

I hope this is useful (if not in this case, then somewhere else).